# How to load mp3 file art with Picasso?

Tags: java, android-studio, picasso

I am working on a music app. How do I load the image art of each songs please?

Thank you!

```
//Set Image
        String uri = newSong_list.get(position).getPath(); >>>. this uri gives me the songs path(EXP:".storage/"song Name.mp3"


        Picasso.get().load()
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .error(ImageResources[randomNumber()])
                .into(holder.SongCover);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "Picasso" can work with songs, in any case the easiest way to use "Picasso" is like: `Picasso.get().load("$url/path").into(name of your view)`

You can try following [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/23916/fetch-audio-mp3-files-from-specific-folder-of-device-or-fetch-all-files)

Comment: If I cannot use Picasso is there something else I can use?

Comment: You should try following the tutorial above. It shows how to read music from your phone :D